# JacksonXML: Resolve inconventional json field name without annotation

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I have a java project where one of my packages contain a lot of dataclasses. These classes are used with deserialization. Currently the package depends on fasterXML only because one of my classes has this field:

```java
String eMail;
```

I would like to remove the dependency to fasterXML but I have the following problem.

```java
val mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  
// Produces UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "eMail" 
// because by default it expects eMail with a lower case 'm'
val res1 = mapper.readValue("{\"eMail\":\"asd\"}", PP.class);
  
// BTW this Produces '{"email":"asd"}'  --> 'm' in eMail is lower case!
val res2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(new PP() {{setEMail("asd");}});
```

Where the PP class is

```java
@Getter
@Setter
private static class PP {
    private String eMail;
}
```

I CANNOT change the json format!

Is it possible to somehow correctly `readValue(PP)` without using the `JsonProperty` annotation? Maybe configuring the `objectMapper` somehow?
The only field I have problem is this one. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make an intermediate class

```
@Getter
@Setter
private static class IntermediatePP {
    private String email;

    public PP convert() {
        PP output = new PP();
        output.setEMail(this.email);
        return output
    }
}
```

Then change your code to

```
val res1 = mapper.readValue("{\"eMail\":\"asd\"}",
                     IntermediatePP.class).convert();
```